# Android: arrayAdapter throwing null pointer exception?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm having some issues with an array adapter.

this is what is in my lessonNotesList class:

```
     mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    //Creating an ArrayList of contacts data
    ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllLessonNotes();
    //Creating an Array Adapter to manipulate the contacts data into a ListView
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_layout, array_list);
    //Adding the contacts to the list view.
    lessonNote = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lessonNote.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    //Setting an onClickListener to process the user's actions
    lessonNote.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Prepare the data from the ListView item to be passed to new activity
            //arg2 is increased by one as its a zero based index but the contacts table in the database works of a base index of 1

            int id_To_Search = VALUE;
            //Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);
            Log.d("Id is ^&*: ", String.valueOf(id_To_Search));
            //Create a new intent to open the DisplayContact activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.LessonNotes.class);
            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

DBHelper class:

```
public ArrayList getAllLessonNotes()
{
    ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from "+TABLE_LESSON_NOTES, null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    while(res.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DATE)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

The code crashes with a NULL pointer exception here:

```
lessonNote.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Any ideas why this is happening? 
I've tried debugging and the debugger is telling me that the arrayAdatper contains 1 entry as it should

I have nearly the same code for a different page and it's working 100% fine..

Any suggestions would be welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about that line ?

```
lessonNote = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

It seems that in your layout XML, no view have "listView1" id.

Comment: Whoops - yes, that was it - it's working now - been looking at this code for too long!! Thanks